# What architecture to use for my ASP.NET Application?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

Here is the scenario:
There's a data source sitting at site A that I could communicate using a set of APIs to get data I need.
I want to build an ASP.NET web application that periodically fetch data from site A and update/store the data in my own database. And periodically process the data and store processing results in my database so that users could browse the results in my web application front-end.

I have no clue how to design the architecture? How to achieve things like periodically communicate with another data source and process data in my database periodically in a web application?

I have very little experience designing web applications. It would be really nice if you could elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to:

"How to achieve things like periodically communicate with another data source and process data in my database periodically in a web application?"

I do this by creating a web service, then creating a console application.  I use Windows Task Scheduler to run the console application at an interval of my choice.  The task is run and the web service is called, which communicates with various data sources and processes the data.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of vague to answer.

There are tools that help with the communication with each API, some services provide wrappers for communication. When they are not provided look into something like Hammock as a wrapper.

High level helps, they are not ABSOLUTEs, just tips and thoughts

- Follow a mutli-tiered model where you clearly separate your layers

  - Model
  - View
  - Controller
- Use an ORM like ServiceStack for data access
- Create a small console app to do the processing

  - Use a schedule job in windows to run it.
  - DONT do this with something like Quartz ( way too much overhead )
  - DONT do with with SqlServerAgent, too much overhead, not enough control if you are a .net Programmer
- Watch how big your objects and lists are getting you will run out of memory when working with other people's data
- Use JSON it is a great format to pass data around within and external to your application
- Setup logging make sure it works, other peoples data breaks
- Scrub incoming data, you can't assume other people's data is clean.
- Profile your application to know where the hot paths are
- Write unit tests
- Run your unit tests regularly.
- Test on multiple browser

Thats probably good for now. Clarify your question and we may be able to give more help.